# C Why is an unrelated/undeclared variable influencing the output of another?

Tags: c, substring, strncpy

When the character array `substring[#]` is set as `[64]`, the file outputs an additional character. The additional character varies with each compile.  Sometimes `es?`, sometimes `esx` among others.

If I change the `[64]` to any other number (at least the ones I've tried: 65, 256,1..) it outputs correctly as `es`.

Even more strange, if I leave the unused/undeclared character array `char newString[64]` in this file, it outputs the correct substring `es` even with the 64.

1. How does the seemingly arbitrary size of 64 affect the out?
2. How does a completely unrelated character array (`newString`) influence how another character array is output?

.

```
int main () {
    char string[64];    
    char newString[64];
    char substring[64];

    fgets(string,64,stdin); 
    strncpy(substring, string+1, 1);
    printf("%s\n", substring);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Watch out for correct use of `strncpy`; it does not append a terminating zero. It appears as if you think it will "extract" a substring out of another.

Comment: Your program has Undefined Behaviour. So the whole premise of your question is wrong - there is no point asking for an explanation for the behaviour of UB. Your question should be - where is the bug in my code. The answer to that is probably here: `strncpy(substring, string+1, 1)`. `string+1` skips the entire string buffer and points to the byte after it. And you also only copy 1 byte and then try to print it as a string.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @kaylum: "`string+1` skips the entire string buffer..." - that is not true. `string+1` points to `string[1]`, exactly as the OP intended it to. It does not skip the entire buffer. The behavior is indeed undefined, but for completely different reasons (see iharob's answer)

Comment: It's usually a good idea to initialize your buffers if you are hoping for well defined behavior.  So, I would change your variable declarations to look like this: ```char string[64] = {0};```

Comment: @bruceg If you don't know what the input will be. But doing that is like trying magic. You should not guess or assume when you write programs, nor should you make everything safe by ignoring possible errors. Well written code can be safe of UB without forcing all zeroes like you say. This is the equivalent of calling a function twice "*just to be sure*", which not surprisingly you can see in some software code here and there.

Comment: @iharob what you say is true, but since he wants to copy a single character into the substring array and print it out, he can guarantee that it will be printable by correctly initializing the array.

Comment: Then you mean `char string[64] = {[1] = 0};`!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, [strncpy()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) will not copy the `null` terminator because you've asked it not to.

Using `strncpy()` is safe and dangerous at the same time, because it will not always copy the `null` terminator, also using it for a single byte is pointless, instead do this

```
substring[0] = string[1];
substring[1] = '\0';
```

and it shall work.

You should read the manual page [strncpy(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) to understand what I mean correctly, if you read the manual carefully every time you would become a better programmer in a shorter time.

Comment: I'd suggest to test if string has a length of at least 2 in order not to take over characters after the actual string end (which is probably not intended). e.g. if (strlen(string) >= 2) substring[0] = string[1] else substring[0] = '\0';

Comment: @StephanLechner It would be very good practice to check, I will not alter the answer since the comment is enough.